# How do i link files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So my example is, I'm writing a Discord bot so that when I type a command in chat it will return the corresponding value.

Now I'm starting off with ammo for this game, the problem being there is a fair few different types of ammo in the game. Since I am new to coding and Python I wanted to get into the habit of separating them into different `.py` files so my codes isn't all messed and i can jump between them easily and keep track of everything down the line.

In my main file there isn't anything but `import shotgun_1, shotgun_2`.
What I noticed, though, is that only `shotgun_1` commands will be recognized; `shotgun_2` doesn't work.

If I remove `shotgun_1` and have only `import shotgun_2` then the `shotgun_2` code will work and send in the chat "HI!". If i remove `shotgun_2` and only use `shotgun_1` then the commands of `shotgun_1` work.

Is there a way to somehow link these two files so they execute the same time?

## shotgun_1.py

````py
import discord
import os
import shotgun_2

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
       
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return

   if message.content.startswith('1270 all'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **5.25mm Buckshot** ``` DAMAGE: 8x37  PenPower: 1  Armor Damage: 15%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **8.5 mm "Magnum" Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 8x50  PenPower: 2 Armor Damage: 26%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **6.5 mm "Express" Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 9x35  PenPower: 3 Armor Damage: 26%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **7mm Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 8x39  PenPower: 3 Armor Damage:26%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **Flechette** ```DAMAGE: 8x25  PenPower: 31 Armor Damage: 26%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **RIP** ```DAMAGE: 265  PenPower: 2 Armor Damage: 11%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **HP Slug "SuperFormance"** ```DAMAGE: 220  PenPower: 5 Armor Damage: 12%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **Grizzly 40 Slug** ```DAMAGE: 190  PenPower: 12 Armor Damage: 48%```')
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **HP Slug Copper Sabot Premier** ```DAMAGE: 206  PenPower: 14 Armor Damage: 46%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **Led slug** ```DAMAGE: 167  PenPower: 15 Armor Damage: 55%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **"Poleva-3" Slug** ```DAMAGE: 140  PenPower: 17 Armor Damage: 40%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **Dual Sabot Slug** ```DAMAGE: 2x85 PenPower: 17 Armor Damage: 65%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **FTX Custom LIte Slug** ```DAMAGE: 183  PenPower: 20 Armor Damage: 50%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **"Poleva-6u" Slug** ```DAMAGE: 150  PenPower: 20 Armor Damage: 50%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **shell with .50 BMG bullet** ```DAMAGE: 197  PenPower: 26 Armor Damage: 57%```')
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **AP-20 Slug** ```DAMAGE: 164  PenPower: 37 Armor Damage: 65%```')
   if message.content.startswith('5m buck'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **5.25mm Buckshot** ``` DAMAGE: 8x37  PenPower: 1  Armor Damage: 15%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 magnum'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **8.5 mm "Magnum" Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 8x50  PenPower: 2 Armor Damage: 26%```')     
   if message.content.startswith('1270 express'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **6.5 mm "Express" Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 9x35  PenPower: 3 Armor Damage: 26%```')
   if message.content.startswith(' 7m buck'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **7mm Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 8x39  PenPower: 3 Armor Damage:26%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 Flechette'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **Flechette** ```DAMAGE: 8x25  PenPower: 31 Armor Damage: 26%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 rip'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **RIP** ```DAMAGE: 265  PenPower: 2 Armor Damage: 11%```')     
   if message.content.startswith('1270 hp Super'):
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **HP Slug "SuperFormance"** ```DAMAGE: 220  PenPower: 5 Armor Damage: 12%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 led'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **Led slug** ```DAMAGE: 167  PenPower: 15 Armor Damage: 55%```') 
   if message.content.startswith('1270 poleva 3'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **"Poleva-3" Slug** ```DAMAGE: 140  PenPower: 17 Armor Damage: 40%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 sabot'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **Dual Sabot Slug** ```DAMAGE: 2x85 PenPower: 17 Armor Damage: 65%```')     
   if message.content.startswith('1270 lite'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **FTX Custom LIte Slug** ```DAMAGE: 183  PenPower: 20 Armor Damage: 50%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 poleva 6'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **"Poleva-6u" Slug** ```DAMAGE: 150  PenPower: 20 Armor Damage: 50%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 50 bmg'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **shell with .50 BMG bullet** ```DAMAGE: 197  PenPower: 26 Armor Damage: 57%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 ap20'):
    await message.channel.send('12x70 **AP-20 Slug** ```DAMAGE: 164  PenPower: 37 Armor Damage: 65%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 Grizzly'): 
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **Grizzly 40 Slug** ```DAMAGE: 190  PenPower: 12 Armor Damage: 48%```')
   if message.content.startswith('1270 HP copper'): 
    await message.channel.send('12/70 **HP Slug Copper Sabot Premier** ```DAMAGE: 206  PenPower: 14 Armor Damage: 46%```')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
````

## shotgun_2.py

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')
```

If anyone can help i would really appreciate it!

Comment: I would suggest that you *don't* separate these into different files. It would be better to use Object-Oriented Programming (OOP), as that would also increase code readability.

Comment: dude, firstly thank you for going through that and making it so pretty! in regards to OOP I'm not sure what that is? I'm only using python and it seems that's the only way to code for the discord bots, I could be wrong but like I said I'm new so I could be 100% wrong

Comment: Actually, after reviewing your code a bit more in-depth, I realize that you don't need to use OOP for this. [OOP](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) isn't a programming language, but is a way for structuring your programs. While it isn't necessary here, it is a good habit to get into once you understand the fundamentals of Python. For `discord.py`, OOP would involve using cogs, which you can read more about [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html), if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not separating these two aspects into different files. `shotgun_2.py` does not contain any code that could not be put into `shotgun_1.py`. This is also why `shotgun_2.py` doesn't do anything when `shotgun_1.py` runs. Your current method imports `shotgun_2.py`, but it doesn't *do* anything after it imports. I cut out large chunks of code, but here are my edits:

```py
import discord
import os

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
       
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return

    if message.content.startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi!")

   --snip--

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

This should allow the bot to run properly, as you intended it to.

While it is outside the scope of this question, I would recommend some re-formatting of all your `if` statements. I would recommend using a dictionary to store all the possible responses and the corresponding messages to send.

For example:

````py
ammo_types = {
    "5m buck": "12/70 **5.25mm Buckshot** ``` DAMAGE: 8x37  PenPower: 1  Armor Damage: 15%```",
    "1270 magnum": '12/70 **8.5 mm "Magnum" Buckshot** ```DAMAGE: 8x50  PenPower: 2 Armor Damage: 26%```",
    ...
}
````

Then, inside `on_message`, you could simplify all the `if` statements.

```py
if message.content.startswith("1270 all"):
    for opt in ammo_types.values():
        await message.channel.send(opt)
else:
    for ammo in ammo_types:
        if message.content.startswith(ammo):
            await message.channel.send(ammo_types[ammo])
```

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this right i would create a dictionary with all the possible ammo names values etc, then write ```if message.content.startswith("1270 all"):
    for opt in ammo_types.values():
        await message.channel.send(opt)``` and copy and paste and change the ("1270 all") to whatever  is in the dictionary? again i am really sorry I am new to this, so im not sure if that seccond bit of code does that already for you? many thanks for taking the time out of your day to help.

Comment: **edit** would this again be the case of leaving it in main file or would i have to create a new file and link it?

Comment: This would be in your `on_message` function, in place of the series of `if` statements you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

The `client.run` that is necessary at the end of your file is a synchronous operation (i.e. it blocks the process). When you do `import shotgun_1, shotgun_2`, Python never finishes loading `shotgun_1` since it is still running, so it never gets to load `shotgun_2`.

In order for both of these commands to run, you would have to put them in the same `on_message` function.